# Google Drive video does not start on smartphones

Tags: html, video, iframe, google-drive-api

I'm using a code to embed video from Google Drive. It works perfect when I'm watching on desktop. But, when I'm trying to watch the same video on my smartphone, it never starts.

Here is my code:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1MJDhOwhGWOaTZSYzM4ZkRPZDQ/view?autoplay=1 scrolling="no" border="1" bordercolor="red" width="640" height="480" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>
```

Is there any solution for me?

Comment: Check if you have any kind of error in the console. 
At least from this code, you are missing a `"`after the `view?autoplay=1"`

I'm getting a x-frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN" heather error. 
Hope it helps

Comment: I got no errors in console. I forgot a " because my code has a PHP code, looking for the link on the mysql BD. I'm using Openload too and it works properly. I don't know how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have no issue if you use "request Desktop site version" from your mobile browser, to see the video. It worked for me.
Instead of `/view?autoplay=1` on the video link, just use `/preview`

For some reason, Google or Android limit the video streaming functionality.

The other way around, would be to store the video in another platform.

Comment: You're right, I can watch using "Desktop site version", thanks for your advice. But, I will keep searching another solution for this issue. Users are lazy, they always looking for an "easy solution". Only Google Drive doesn't working, Openload and OK.ru for example works properly. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I stumbled upon this problem just now and I couldn't find any google provided solution. As a workaround, I compressed the video the most I could and placed in the HTML as a video with the source from google cloud:

```
<video width="100%" height="300px" controls>
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=VIDEO_ID&export=download&authuser=0" 
    type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Keep in mind that the video has to be public for it to w

Now it works on desktop or on mobile, The only issue is that you sacrifice the google drive embedded controls like quality and captions obviously...